# Formula of morphism $\pi $ to general element $K[x]/(m)$

Tags: ring-homomorphism, morphism

I need to write formula, how morphism $\pi $ is influencing general element of $K[x]/(m)$.

We have field K and polynomial $m \in K[x]$ which is irreducible over K. F is field, which is isomorphic with $K[x]/(m)$ and $\pi$ is their isomorphism.

$\pi : K[x] / (m) \rightarrow F \quad : \quad [x]  \mapsto \alpha $

$\alpha$ is unknown element

I found some definition, which could help me, but I am not sure.

If $\pi$ is homomorphism of ring R to ring S, than ker $\pi$ is ideal of ring R and S is isomorphic to quotient ring $R/ker \pi$. If J is ideal of ring R, than morphism $\pi : R \rightarrow R/J$ is defined by formula $\pi(a) = a + J$ for $a \in R$ is homomorphism $R$ nad $R/J$ with ker $J$

Could someone give me a help with this?

Comment: Take an example. Let $K = \Bbb R$, $m = x^2 + 1$ and $F = \Bbb C$. Then $\pi$ is given by $\pi([a+bx]) = a+bi$. What about this is it that seems mysterious to you?

Comment: @Arthur sorry, I read it so fast, didn't understand it and I wrote nosense in previous comment. Yeah it is clear, problem is, I don't know imagine it in general, becuase actually I don't know what is F and K. So I don't know how to write it in general meaning, where F and K is unkown.